# Import CSS stylesheet only for specific content type?

Tags: theming

I want to use `materializeCSS` for my `Blog` content type. Problem is, when I import the stylesheet (I have set up my content type to process all HTML tags), it does not affect only the area of content of that content type, but it "leaks" to the rest of the theme, and changing overall theme look where CSS classes overlap (like default styling of H2 element in Materialize changes the whole look of the theme). Is there a way/module to have imported CSS stylesheet only affect the content it is imported to, but not the rest of the theme? I tried several modules that deal with context and CSS on sites, but neither of them works.

Comment: There is no way to make css only work on part of the page without adding extra selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your css only on Blog node pages so it does not impact site wide. Sample code

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node($vars) {
  if ($vars['#node']->type == 'blog') {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodulename') . "/css/materializeCSS.css");
  }
}
```